# building shortcut for 'grunt test' inside sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, gruntjs

How would I go about having a shortcut / macro to run 'grunt test'  from within sublime/ Preferably with just 1 keystroke. Best would be to see the output in the sublime console. Any plugin for this?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need plugin.

Sublime Text 2 has extensive, extensible, build system:

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html

- Create your build configuration for `grunt test`
- Trigger it with a hotkey